# Unable to use different colors for fillStyle while drawing on canvas even after using beginPath() and Closepath()

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have tried to find solution from similar questions but none to avail, i have tried placing the ctx.fillStyle in between ctx.beginPath(); and ctx.closePath(); I am able to give different colors to the paddle and bricks but the ball would inherit the color from the bricks, instead of getting the color from the randomColor() function.
Following is the code:-

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height - 30;
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;
var ballRadius = 10;
var paddleHeight = 10;
var paddleWidth = 75;
var paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth) / 2; 
var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var brickRowCount = 3;
var brickColumnCount = 5;
var brickWidth = 75;
var brickHeight = 20;
var brickPadding = 10;
var brickOffsetTop = 30;
var brickOffsetLeft = 30;


document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function randomColor() {
  var i = 0;
  var n = 16777215;
  var string = "#"
  var colorDec = rand(i, n);
  var colorHex = colorDec.toString(16);
  var colorCode = string.concat(colorHex);
  return colorCode;
}


function rand(min, max) {
  var min = min || 0,
    max = max || Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var bricks = [];
for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
  bricks[c] = [];
  for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
    bricks[c][r] = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      status: 1
    };
  }
}

function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = true;
  }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = false;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = false;
  }
}

function collisionDetection() {
  for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
      var b = bricks[c][r];
      if (b.status == 1) {
        if (x > b.x && x < b.x + brickWidth && y > b.y && y < b.y + brickHeight) {
          dy = -dy;
          b.status = 0;
          ctx.fillStyle = randomColor();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fill();
  if (x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
    ctx.fillStyle = randomColor();
  }
  if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius || y + dy < ballRadius) {
    ctx.fillStyle = randomColor();
  }
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawPaddle() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height - paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00a6ff";
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawBricks() {
  for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
      if (bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
        var brickX = (c * (brickWidth + brickPadding)) + brickOffsetLeft;
        var brickY = (r * (brickHeight + brickPadding)) + brickOffsetTop;
        bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
        bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#00a6ff";
        ctx.closePath();
      }
    }
  }
}




function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBall();
  drawPaddle();
  drawBricks();
  collisionDetection();

  if (x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
    dx = -dx;
  }
  if (y + dy < ballRadius) {
    dy = -dy;
  } else if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius) {
    if (x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
      dy = -dy;
    } else {
      alert("GAME OVER");
      document.location.reload();
    }
  }
  if (rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width - paddleWidth) {
    paddleX += 7;
  } else if (leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {
    paddleX -= 7;
  }

  y += dy;
  x += dx;
}
setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
/* canvas x,y origin (0,0) is top left
setInterval(draw,10);  is the game loop
*/
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
/*x, y location of the ball  */
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height - 30;
/*dx,dy no of pixels to move at a time, ie each draw */
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;
var ballRadius = 10;
var paddleHeight = 10;
var paddleWidth = 75;
var paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth) / 2;
var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var brickRowCount = 3;
var brickColumnCount = 5;
var brickWidth = 75;
var brickHeight = 20;
var brickPadding = 10;
var brickOffsetTop = 30;
var brickOffsetLeft = 30;

//JC's extra variables
var brickColours = ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff']; //3 rows each with a different colour
var ballColour = '#eeeeee'; //change the colour when collision light grey
var intervalID = 0; //used to stop game

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function randomColor() {
  var i = 0;
  var n = 16777215;
  var string = "#"
  var colorDec = rand(i, n);
  var colorHex = colorDec.toString(16);
  var colorCode = string.concat(colorHex);
  //console.log('colorCode ', colorCode);
  return colorCode;
}


function rand(min, max) {
  var min = min || 0,
    max = max || Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var bricks = [];

for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
  bricks[c] = [];
  for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
    bricks[c][r] = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      status: 1
    };
  }
}

function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = true;
  }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = false;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = false;
  }
}

function collisionDetection() {
  for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
      var b = bricks[c][r];
      if (b.status == 1) {
        //mark brick as deleted          
        if (x > b.x && x < b.x + brickWidth && y > b.y && y < b.y + brickHeight) {
          dy = -dy;
          b.status = 0;
          //next 2 lines needed? - change colour on collision
          ballColour = randomColor();
          ctx.fillStyle = ballColour;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function drawBall() {
  //if ball is offscreen redraw with a random colour    
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = ballColour;
  //ctx.fill();
  //if moves off screen left or right
  if (x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
    ballColour = randomColor();
    ctx.fillStyle = ballColour;
  }
  //if moves off screen down or up
  if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius || y + dy < ballRadius) {
    ballColour = randomColor();
    ctx.fillStyle = ballColour;
  }
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawPaddle() {
  //always draw with the same colour    
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height - paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
  //ctx.fill();
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00a6ff";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawBricks() {
  /* work through array of bricks and draw all those present, same colour  */

  for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
      //set each row to a different colour
      ctx.fillStyle = brickColours[r];


      //if brick is not deleted draw it
      if (bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
        var brickX = (c * (brickWidth + brickPadding)) + brickOffsetLeft;
        var brickY = (r * (brickHeight + brickPadding)) + brickOffsetTop;
        bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
        bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
        //ctx.fill();
        //ctx.fillStyle = "#00a6ff";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      }
    }
  }
}



//draw is the main loop that drives the game
function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBall();
  drawPaddle();
  drawBricks();
  collisionDetection();

  if (x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
    dx = -dx;
  }
  if (y + dy < ballRadius) {
    dy = -dy;
  } else if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius) {
    if (x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
      dy = -dy;
    } else {
      alert("GAME OVER, reload page to start again");
      clearInterval(intervalID);
      //document.location.reload();
    }
  }

  //move paddleX left or right if in range
  if (rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width - paddleWidth) {
    paddleX += 7;
  } else if (leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {
    paddleX -= 7;
  }

  y += dy;
  x += dx;
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  background: #eee;
  /* grey */
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>breakout problem</h1>
<button onclick="intervalID=setInterval(draw, 10);">Play</button>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

Comment: Colour changes:wall - each row has a colour,
ball - changes colour with a collision with brick or wall,
paddle - colour does not change

Comment: Thank you, can you explain where was i messing up?